# Text Box overlapping Label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded a theme from [startbootstrap.com](http://www.bootstrap.com) and tried to add a login box using a dropdown (code from which came from [bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/flatly/#). 
**The problem** I have is , that the **textbox is overlapping the text labels** & though i have tried to change the width almost all divs but have not been able to solve the problem.

The code is :

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset style="width : 450px" ;>
        <div class="form-group" style="width:400px";>
            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label" width="100px" >Email</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10"  sytle="width : 60px";>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail"   placeholder="Email"  style="cursor: auto; background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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); background-attachment: scroll; background-position: 100% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat; width:150px" ;>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="width:400px"; >
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label" width="100px" >Password</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword"  placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" style="cursor: auto; background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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); background-attachment: scroll; background-position: 100% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat; width:150px ; ;>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Please guide me about where am I going wrong.
I have very little programming experience.

Thanks

Comment: can you please add a fiddle too..

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/krqhz2a0/) is what your code lokks like..

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little. I have no idea what fiddle is ?

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/#run) is a site where you can paste the codes and share the links with us so that we can understand the problem better..check my earlier comment in which i've done one for you..is that what you expected..??

Comment: @Lal : Nopes please see the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/7igv10w1tl1vxmz/snapshot.png?dl=0, this is what I am trying to achieve, but overlapping is something I am not able to correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tidied up your code. There were some basic errors (Missing "s and /s).

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset style="width : 450px">
    <label style="display:block;" for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label" width="100px">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" style="cursor: auto; background-attachment: scroll; background-position: 100% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat; width:150px;" />

    <label style="display:block;" for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label" width="100px">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" style="cursor: auto; background-attachment: scroll; display:block; background-position: 100% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat; width:150px;" />
    <button style="display:block;" type="submit" class="btn-primary">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uhmhL628/1/

Try this and see if it works for you. luc122c

Comment: Hi, The problem has reversed. The label now overlaps the textbox. Have added a snapshot here https://www.dropbox.com/s/7igv10w1tl1vxmz/snapshot.png?dl=0

Comment: Can you add your css into the fiddle, it's probably a formatting issue.

Comment: Hi, There are 3 css files. I tried to use tidyUp in fiddle. The links are http://jsfiddle.net/56b6n85b/  ;  http://jsfiddle.net/bmfecnzd/  ;  http://jsfiddle.net/eary14f5/
but the problem still persists.